# Signature thickness of vue signature pad

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, html5-canvas, signaturepad

I am using https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad this package for drawing signatures in my vuejs project. But can't find any way to reduce the thickness of the signature. Is there any way?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

add the options in the template

```
<VueSignaturePad id="myId" :options="signOptions"/>
```

then add to data this

```
signOptions: {
  minWidth: 0.5,
  maxWidth: 6,
},
```

minWidth and maxWidth define the stroke width on the pad
it's all in the documentation so read it more for additional options, some of the options miss documentation so you might have to experiment a little with it